# how to get the specific result according to a certain condition in MongoDb through mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to get the articles of the specific user through mongoose, how can I do it? as my code:

```
Content.find().sort({_id:-1}).populate(['category','user']).then(function (content) {
                res.render('admin/content_list',{
                    pid:req_pid,
                    title:'博客管理后台',
                    userInfo:req.userInfo,
                    contents: content
                })
            })
```

I get all the articles through this, but what i want is a result that belongs to certain user, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
Content.find({userid:USERID}).sort({_id:-1}).populate(['category','user']).then(function (content) {
                res.render('admin/content_list',{
                    pid:req_pid,
                    title:'博客管理后台',
                    userInfo:req.userInfo,
                    contents: content
                })
            })
```

Where USERID is the ObjectId of the user.

You probably also want to take a look at this: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html, assuming you are using mongoose.

Comment: Won't this search for content documents with an user document ID? It looks like the person asking the question has a separate user model which they reference and populate, thus making this answer not work.

Comment: @SjoerdDal You are completely right. I've updated the answer to correct this.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter results for a specific user by using their objectId. As long as you have that ID you can do something like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;

Content.find({
        user: new ObjectId(userId)
    })
    .sort({_id: -1})
    .populate(['category', 'user'])
    .exec((err, results) => {

    });
```